# EdgeRenderingFunction For 2 Vertices in a Loop

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, replacement, style

Assume there is a set of rules:

```
set = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "A", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "D", "D" -> "A", "C" -> "C"};
```

which we want to graph using `LayeredGraphPLot`, and we want to impose the rule that any pair of vertices that have 2 edges going between them, in *different* directions ("A" -> "B" and "B" -> "A"), that those edges be a different color, style, etc.

Here is my code:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[set, DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[MemberQ[Reverse /@ set, #] &,
 {Black, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[#1, 0.05]}, {Blue, 
  Thickness[0.01], Arrow[#1, 0.05]}] &)]
```

which does not produce the desired result (vertices with 2 edges in different directions be black, the rest blue).  In fact, the code draws no edges at all, just the vertices.  My thinking was to apply the `Reverse` function to the original `set` and then see if the current rule in the slot was a member of the reversed set, which should be the case for `A->B` and `B->A`.

However I get the error: "If is not a Graphics primitive or directive."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LayeredGraphPlot[set, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({If[MemberQ[set /. Rule -> List, Reverse@#2] && ! SameQ @@ #2, 
                              Black, Blue], Arrow[#1, 0.1]} &)]
```

[image]

Remove the *SameQ* check if you want self-loops to be considered a hit. If you expect lager graphs, probably wise to pre-compute some stuff...

Per OP comment, the reason the slot used is 2 (from the documentation page):

[image]

So, the first slot refers to the points used to generate the graphic of the graph, the second is the vertices. You can sow/reap the values and take a look to get an intuitive feel for what's passed.

Comment: Works great, thanks.  Not sure I understand why it's `#2` rather than `#` or `#1`, could you please clarify and add to your answer?

Comment: @iwantmyphd See doc. On EdgeRenderingFunction, that's slot used here for edge info. I'm mobile, will add to answer on return.

Comment: I'm thinking about expanding this question to cover the situation in which the two edges that form a loop between two vertices could be drawn as a single *bidirectional* arrow instead.  If this is possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
multipleedges = Alternatives @@ List @@@ Select[set, Count[set, # | Reverse[#]] > 1 &];
erf = {#2 /. {multipleedges :> Black, _ :> Blue}, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[#1, 0.05]} &;

LayeredGraphPlot[set, DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `Graph`:

```
Graph[Flatten[
Values[GroupBy[set,Sort]]/.{{x_, y_} :> {Style[x, Black],Style[y, Black]},
{x_} :> Style[x, Blue]}],
GraphLayout ->"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```